# Rescale image accordingly to background image.

Tags: css

I have this web with a background defined this way in css:

```
body{
background-image:url(BackgroundImage.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

And then I have several other Images on top of that placed at certain positions. like this for an example:

```
#Logo{
position: absolute;
top:92px;
left:95px;
}
```

However what I need is for the logo image to scale accordingly to the background image.

So I guess what I kinda need to tell the Logo image Is that whatever size you have at the moment Is = 100% and whenever I scale the window then you need to act accordingly.

Thx for any contributions in advance!

Comment: Can you make some fiddle ? Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0Lcpm3v/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the form input? And what is the relationship between the input and the logo? Is that a button?

Comment: yes the logo is a botton to the homepage. 

the background image is designed with frames that a menu and logo fit into. that screws up when i rescale the window. 

So i need all webcontent to scale with the background image.

Comment: Then that's nothing to do with the body but the frame which you need to show more codes.

Comment: the frames are the background picture. they are painted on to it in photoshop. there is no code to show. 

Lets try this way. 

i have a background picture 1920x1080 and on that picture aka same jpg is a line 4x4 drawn. 

then i have another trimmed 4x4 picture with a 4x4 drawn line in it. This picture is placed next to the 4x4 line in the background image. 

now what i need to do is to make these two 4x4 lines on two different pictures with different sizes  to be equally big no matter how i scale the browser window.

Comment: short way of saying this is that i want a picture to scale as if it was 1920x1080 although the picture is only 4x4

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id="logo"></div>
</body>

#logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:5%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 18%;
  background-image: url(logo.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/h2am5zkg/

You would need to set everything in percentage

Comment: Well yeah this does indeed make my logo image scale but far from the sense that i want i to. 

You need to imagine that i have a special designed background image with frames that a menu and logo fit into. And atm when i rescale my window. this logo and menu goes outside its frames.

Comment: if you saw the picture you would know why i dont place the frames individually from the background image. Unfortunately i dont have enough reputation to post an Image.